# SKStoreReviewController is being displayed the first time user launches the app

Tags: ios, swift, skstorereviewcontroller

In my iOS app I'm using SKStoreReviewController to request users to rate the app. The Apple documentation says to put the code for requesting the "Rate Us" popup anywhere we want, and they will govern when it will be actually displayed. 
I wrote the following code in the first view of the app:

```
func requestReview() {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```

The problem is that the popup is displayed to my app's users as soon as they first launch the app, which makes no sense. Is there any way to control the popup's appearance and avoid showing it before certain amount of uses of the app?

Comment: It will only show at the time that you call that function, the Apple documentation just means that they get to decide whether that function actually shows the alert or just does nothing.

Comment: Is they get to decide it, how come they decide to show it in the first launch of the app? It would make more sense to show it after the user uses the app for a while

Comment: AFAIK the only decision they make when they decide to show it is whether or not you have been showing it too often (in which case they stop you from showing it again).  They don't do anything to attempt to determine if it is a good time to show it or not, that is on you to decide before calling the function.

Comment: Some more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976072/skstorereviewcontroller-requestreview-may-or-may-not-present-and-alert?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` **will** display the popup for the first few times ([to be exact](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/), for the first 3 times in a year).

Create a variable that you increment each time in your application delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method and save it to UserDefaults. After that, you can check whether a user opened the app enough times.

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    var appLaunches = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "appLaunches")
    appLaunches += 1
    UserDefaults.standard.set(appLaunches, forKey: "appLaunches")

    return true
}
```

**The view controller where you want to display the store review controller**

```
let appLaunches = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "appLaunches")

if appLaunches >= [enough number of app launches] {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```